# Correct way to do ‘Became friends’ activity without ‘doubling’ up in [getStream]

Tags: php, laravel-5, getstream-io

Using Laravel and getStream.

Current structure:

A User has a feed on their dashboard which is a merge of `FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($request->user()->id)['timeline’];` && `FeedManager::getUserFeed($request->user()->id);`

This works fine however ‘double ups’ of activities occur when we’re trying to do a ‘became friends’ activity.

If Joe follows Jane he will see

`Jane is now friends with Joe`

`Joe is now friends with Jane`

Ideally: We'd just have `Joe is now friends with Jane` and if the current user is Joe adjust it to `You are now friends with Jane`

Same also happens if Joe follows Sam and Peter, and they then become friends.

Joe’s feed:

`Sam is now friends with Peter`

`Peter is now friends with Sam`

Ideally: We'd get `Sam and Peter are now friends` (order doesn't really matter)

What is the best way to do this kind of tracking (or filtering) with getStream?

(Is their a singular Activity that references to both users?)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're pulling each feed separately, and since we don't have an understanding of what your actor/verb/object means, it isn't possible for Stream to de-duplicate or rename these events since you're already merging them together. You'd likely be sending us a unique id for 'Joe' already, so you'd need a logic check on your side to say something like (pseudo-code):

```
$bits = $activity->actor.split(":");
$activity_user = get_user_details($bits[1]);
$actor_is = $activity_user->name . " is";
if ($user->id == $activity_user->id) {
    $actor_is = "You are";
}
$output = $actor_is . " now following ...";
```

We don't allow filtering on activity data when fetching a feed's activities. Our filtering rules are more about pagination.